# How do I line up my button in twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, inline

[image]

Hi im trying to line up my button horizontally like an "inline" but it wont let me. I know about btn-group but then I cant have space in between the buttons like I want because they're attached to one another. so im trying to align them horizontally without btn-group
**Here is my code:**

```
<footer class="bottom visible-phone">
   <div class="container">
      <div class="row text-center">
   <div class="span1"><a class="btn btn-primary btn-small" href="#">
  <div class="icon-user icon-white"></div> Facebook</a></div>
   <div class="span1"><a class="btn btn-info btn-small" href="#">
  <div class="icon-user icon-white"></div> Twitter</a></div>
   <div class="span1"><a class="btn btn-danger btn-small" href="#">
  <div class="icon-user icon-white"></div> Youtube</a></div>
   <div class="span1"><a class="btn btn-small" href="#">
  <div class="icon-user"></div> Instagram</a></div>
</div><!--row END-->
</div><!--container END-->
</footer>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootsrap, the grid system (span, row, container) will make all span's appear underneath eachother as soon as you get to the 'phone' size (which I guess is the case here, due to the visible-phone class you added to the footer). You won't be able to rely just on the grid system for this...

There is however a .inline class available to use on `ul`: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#lists

This means that with some reformatting of your markup (which would make sense anyway), you should be able to achieve the desired result, without writing a single line of css yourself:

```
<footer class="bottom visible-phone">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row text-center">
            <ul class='inline span12'>
                <li><a class="btn btn-primary btn-small" href="#">
                    <i class="icon-user icon-white"></i> Facebook</a>
                </li>
                ...
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!--row END-->
    </div>
    <!--container END-->
</footer>
```

In fact all the extra wrappers (footer, container, row) are not required here, I just kept them as they where present in your code. Only the code from `<ul>` (without the .span12) to `</ul>` should do.

For an example, have a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/jRm3Z/1/

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend makeing the Row div a UL and the other elements in the list LI tags.
Then you should be able to modify your css code:

```
display: list-item;
```

or

```
display: block;
```

UPDATE #:

```
<div class="icon-user icon-white"></div>
```

Replace with

```
<i class="icon-user icon-white"></div>
```

Comment: I was hoping that there would be a way without have to make a list via bootstrap classes

Comment: I've tried it myself but you could try to replace the CSS code to work with how you coded it above.